# DimensionMisMatch Error Just Before Training

Tags: machine-learning, julia, mlp, flux.jl

I’m trying to train a MLP model to predict number of real roots of polynomials. x_train and y_train include array of arrays such as [[-204, 20, 13, 1, 0]] which are coefficients of polynomials. x_test and y_test include number of real roots of each polynomial such 1,2,5… I have polynomials up to 100 degree therefore 101 expresses that. I’m stuck in this error. I’m trying to give data to MLP properly but I couldn’t do it even though I tried so hard. Can you please help me about this issue?

Here is my code:

```
using Flux

function input()
    ## x_train
    lines = Tuple(readlines("/home/user/Desktop/x_train.txt"))
    x_train = []

    for i in lines
        push!(x_train, convert(Array{Float32},eval(Meta.parse(i))))
    end

    x_train = reshape(x_train, 2, :)
    ## y_train
    lines = Tuple(readlines("/home/user/Desktop/y_train.txt"))
    y_train = []

    for i in lines
        push!(y_train, eval(Meta.parse(i)))
    end
    
    y_train = reshape(y_train, 2, :)

    ## x_test
    lines = Tuple(readlines("/home/user/Desktop/x_test.txt"))
    x_test = []

    for i in lines
        push!(x_test, convert(Array{Float32},eval(Meta.parse(i))))
    end

    x_test = reshape(x_test, 1, :)

    ## y_test
    lines = Tuple(readlines("/home/user/Desktop/y_test.txt"))
    y_test = []

    for i in lines
        push!(y_test, eval(Meta.parse(i)))
    end
    
    y_test = reshape(y_test, 1, :)

    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
end

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = input()

train_size = 18

function NeuralNetwork()
    return Chain(
            Dense(2, 9,relu),
            Dense(9,101), softmax
            )
end

# Organizing the data in batches
X    = hcat(x_train,y_train)
Y    = vcat(ones(train_size),zeros(train_size))
Y = reshape(Y, 18, 2)
println(size(X))
println(size(Y))
data = Flux.Data.DataLoader((X, Y'), batchsize=100,shuffle=true);
# Defining our model, optimization algorithm and loss function
m    = NeuralNetwork()
opt = Descent(0.05)
loss(x, y) = sum(Flux.Losses.binarycrossentropy(m(x), y))

ps = Flux.params(m)
epochs = 20
for i in 1:epochs
    Flux.train!(loss, ps, data, opt)
end
```

Here is the error message I got:

```
ERROR: LoadError: DimensionMismatch("dimensions must match: a has dims (Base.OneTo(5),), b has dims (Base.OneTo(4),), mismatch at 1")
```

Stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace:
  [1] promote_shape
    @ ./indices.jl:178 [inlined]
  [2] promote_shape
    @ ./indices.jl:169 [inlined]
  [3] +(A::Vector{Float32}, Bs::Vector{Float32})
    @ Base ./arraymath.jl:45
  [4] adjoint
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/lib/array.jl:782 [inlined]
  [5] _pullback(__context__::Zygote.Context, 614::typeof(+), A::Vector{Float32}, B::Vector{Float32})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/ZygoteRules/AIbCs/src/adjoint.jl:65
  [6] _pullback
    @ /opt/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:889 [inlined]
  [7] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra._generic_matmatmul!), ::Matrix{Any}, ::Char, ::Char, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Any}, ::LinearAlgebra.MulAddMul{true, true, Bool, Bool})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
  [8] _pullback
    @ /opt/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:798 [inlined]
  [9] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra.generic_matmatmul!), ::Matrix{Any}, ::Char, ::Char, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Any}, ::LinearAlgebra.MulAddMul{true, true, Bool, Bool})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [10] _pullback
    @ /opt/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:302 [inlined]
 [11] _pullback
    @ /opt/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:275 [inlined]
 [12] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(LinearAlgebra.mul!), ::Matrix{Any}, ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Any})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [13] _pullback
    @ /opt/julia-1.7.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/LinearAlgebra/src/matmul.jl:153 [inlined]
 [14] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(*), ::Matrix{Float32}, ::Matrix{Any})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [15] _pullback
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/layers/basic.jl:158 [inlined]
 [16] _pullback(ctx::Zygote.Context, f::Dense{typeof(relu), Matrix{Float32}, Vector{Float32}}, args::Matrix{Any})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [17] _pullback
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/layers/basic.jl:47 [inlined]
 [18] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(Flux.applychain), ::Tuple{Dense{typeof(relu), Matrix{Float32}, Vector{Float32}}, Dense{typeof(identity), Matrix{Float32}, Vector{Float32}}, typeof(softmax)}, ::Matrix{Any})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [19] _pullback
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/layers/basic.jl:49 [inlined]
 [20] _pullback(ctx::Zygote.Context, f::Chain{Tuple{Dense{typeof(relu), Matrix{Float32}, Vector{Float32}}, Dense{typeof(identity), Matrix{Float32}, Vector{Float32}}, typeof(softmax)}}, args::Matrix{Any})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [21] _pullback
    @ ~/Desktop/mlp.jl:67 [inlined]
 [22] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::typeof(loss), ::Matrix{Any}, ::Matrix{Float64})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [23] _apply
    @ ./boot.jl:814 [inlined]
 [24] adjoint
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/lib/lib.jl:200 [inlined]
 [25] _pullback
    @ ~/.julia/packages/ZygoteRules/AIbCs/src/adjoint.jl:65 [inlined]
 [26] _pullback
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/optimise/train.jl:105 [inlined]
 [27] _pullback(::Zygote.Context, ::Flux.Optimise.var"#39#45"{typeof(loss), Tuple{Matrix{Any}, Matrix{Float64}}})
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0
 [28] pullback(f::Function, ps::Zygote.Params)
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface.jl:352
 [29] gradient(f::Function, args::Zygote.Params)
    @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/umM0L/src/compiler/interface.jl:75
 [30] macro expansion
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/optimise/train.jl:104 [inlined]
 [31] macro expansion
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Juno/n6wyj/src/progress.jl:134 [inlined]
 [32] train!(loss::Function, ps::Zygote.Params, data::Flux.Data.DataLoader{Tuple{Matrix{Any}, LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}}, Random._GLOBAL_RNG}, opt::Descent; cb::Flux.Optimise.var"#40#46")
    @ Flux.Optimise ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/optimise/train.jl:102
 [33] train!(loss::Function, ps::Zygote.Params, data::Flux.Data.DataLoader{Tuple{Matrix{Any}, LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}}, Random._GLOBAL_RNG}, opt::Descent)
    @ Flux.Optimise ~/.julia/packages/Flux/BPPNj/src/optimise/train.jl:100
 [34] top-level scope
    @ ~/Desktop/mlp.jl:72
in expression starting at /home/user/Desktop/mlp.jl:71
```

My x_train.txt:

```
[1, 2, 5]
[2, 1, 4, 5]
[3, 1, 4, 54, 2]
[21,4,23,1]
[1,46,3,687,231,12]
[12,4,62,8,0,4]
[1,5,1,7,0,53,6,7,2]
[1,5,1,7,0,53,7,2]
[12,4,62,8,0,4,23]
[21,4,23,1,1241]
[1123, 2, 53]
[211, 1, 4, 56]
[35, 1, 4, 54, 72]
[2154,4,23,15]
[112,46,3,687,231,126]
[112,4,62,8,0,4]
[16,5,1,7,0,53,6,7,21]
[17,5,1,7,0,53,7,22]
```

My y_train.txt:

```
1
4
6
1
4
3
7
5
34
124
1
4
3
7
54
53
35
114
```

x_test.txt is the same with x_train.txt but includes less arrays. Also y_test.txt is the same with y_train.txt but include less numbers.

Comment: Wait until the first malicious user puts `rm("home/user/", recursive=true, force=true)` into the input file :D Seriously, don't use eval here to read numbers.

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the error so we can at least guess where it's happening. We also don't have access to your input files, so we have no idea where dimension lengths of 4 and 5 would come from. Perhaps you can comment the size/types of your inputs throughout the code?

Comment: @BatWannaBe I added stacktrace, txt files and data inside them. Sorry that I didn't write before.